# Bitcoin core crash during IBD

Tags: bitcoin-core, synchronization

I've been running bitcoin core on an android device (nexus 5x) and emulator, and sync on testnet always fails at around 3% progress

the last thing logged is

“pre-allocating up to position 0x900000 in rev00006.dat”

core crashes and when restarting the sync process never restarts getting stuck at

“Failed to open mempool file from disk. Continuing anyway”

Prune is set to 550mb and the device has 2gb ram but 70% seems to be taken up by the OS

Is this issue caused by a lack of ram? Or likely something else?

Answer (score 2):

From my own experience, running ABCore on a Nexus 5X, Android is too eager to kill processes that use a large amount of memory on systems with less than 3 GB.

Comment: Good to know it’s not just my 5x, so likely it is ram, I’m testing versions of config i.e. low dbcache prune size etc sometimes it works, seeing if there is a stable setup that can keep ram low enough, interestingly I have another 3gb device with an older android os which seems ok, but I think that OS is lighter than current ones

Comment: is it expected that if Android kills the process during IBD that the db could get corrupted? as mentioned in my question bitcoin core gets stuck on restart trying to prune the block store, last logs are 

“Failed to open mempool file from disk. Continuing anyway”